# WordPress WP_User_Query

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

How can I show `user` and order them by 2 meta fields? For example I have user query

```
$args = array(
        'role'                => 'specialist',
        'meta_key'            => 'proffession',
        'meta_value'          => $term->ID,
        'meta_compare'        => '=',
        'number'              => 20,
        'paged'               => $paged,
    );
$user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
```

I want to sort this query by two meta_values, for example in PHP:

```
 if(get_usermeta( $user_id, $meta_key = 'be_first' )>time() AND get_usermeta( $user_id, $meta_key = 'pro_date' )>time())
    // show this users first  ordered by be_first DESC, ordered by pro_date
if($pro_date>time()){
    //show this users second ordered by pro_date desc
}
    //show all other users
```

Comment: Hi Alex.  Is `be_first` and `pro_date` set for all users?  Like is there a value for each user in those fields?

Comment: Hi Howard, no this values will be set only to person who buy the pro and be_first

Answer (score 0):

You can try this... I don't have your fields, so this is not tested.  You can create a `meta_query` where your clauses are set to compare `exists` then use those to orderby.

```php
$args = array(
        'role'              => 'specialist',
        'number'            => 20,
        'paged'             => $paged,
        'meta_query'        => array (
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'     => 'profession',
                'value'   => '$term->ID',
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
            'be_first_clause' => array(
                'key'     => 'be_first',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            ),
            'pro_date_clause' => array(
                'key'     => 'pro_date',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            ),
        ),
        'orderby' => array(
            'be_first_clause' => 'ASC',
            'pro_date_clause' => 'ASC'
        )
    );
$user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
```

Comment: its not working for me i have found some code for realizing this for posts but its not working with user https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60732125/wordpress-wp-user-query-combine-query

Comment: i update meta for testing sorting is not working   user with id 2 it need to show first with biggest value to lower value i change this 
'be_first_clause' => 'ASC','be_first_clause' => 'DESC',
update_usermeta( 2,'be_first', 3);
update_usermeta( 3,'be_first', 1);

Comment: I have no way to test this, since they are custom fields on your installation.  If you could update your question with a dump of the results of the query, that might be helpful.